# What is essence of saga orchestrator

Tags: microservices, saga, orchestration

Two simple question about orchestartion

1- What is orchestrator essence? A seperate service that is common between services? Or a logic inside each service that created by each operation and will killed after operation finished?

2- Can we use TCP for connection between Orchestrator and participants or only message brokers accepted?

Comment: 1. A separate service is preferred solution. Also any one service can behave like orchestrator with its own responsibility.  (2.) Message Brokers is preferred.

Comment: Thanks @xs2tarunkukreja for this clear answer